# Redirect User to special content after he installed App

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

For example:
I have User A and User B.
Both Users get a link to Google Play to download my App.
After launching it first time without login or registration i want to redirect User B to other content than User A (Getting Data from DB).
How can I handle it without Firebase Dynamic Links?
How would the link look like?
How to handle it in React-Native?

I tried to find a solution and found Firebase Dynamic Links but would like to realize it without Firebase.